# How to rename one-hot encoded columns in pandas to their respective index?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm one-hot encoding some categorical variables with some code that was provied to me. This line adds a column of 0s and 1s with a name with the format `prefix_categoricalValue`

```
dataframe = pandas.concat([dataframe,pandas.get_dummies(dataframe[0], prefix='protocol')],axis=1).drop([0],axis=1)
```

I want the column to have as a name its index, not `prefix_categoricalValue`.

I know that I can do something like `df.rename(columns={'prefix_categoricalValue': '0'}, inplace=True)`, but I'm not sure how to do it for all the columns which have that prefix.

[image]

This is an example of a part of the dataframe. Whether I decide to leave the local_address prefix or not, each category will have its name. Is it possible to rename the column with its index?

EDIT:

I'm trying to do this:

```
for column in dataframe:
    dataframe.rename(columns={column: 'new_name'}, inplace=True)
        print (column)
```

but I'm not exactly sure why it doesn't work

Comment: can you show us some example ?

Comment: just don't use `prefix` at all?! (it's default value is `None`)

Comment: @Peyman I would still end up with column names with out the prefixes, for example: category1, category2, ..., categoryN

Answer (score 3):

```
import pandas as pd

# 'dataframe' is the name of your data frame in the question, so that's what I use
# in my code below, although I suggest using 'data' or something for it instead, 
# as 'DataFrame' is a keyword and its easy to make confusion. But anyway...

features = ['list of column names you want one-hot encoded']
# for example, features = ['Cars', 'Model, 'Year', ... ]

for f in features: 
    df = dataframe[[f]]

    df2 = (pd.get_dummies(df, prefix='', prefix_sep='')
                   .max(level=0, axis=1)
                   .add_prefix(f+' - '))  
    # the new feature names will be "<old_feature_name> - <categorical_value>"
    # for example, "Cars" will get transformed to "Cars - Minivan", "Cars - Truck", etc


    # add the new one-hot encoded column to the dataframe
    dataframe = pd.concat([dataframe, df2], axis=1)

    # you can remove the original columns, if you don't need them anymore (optional)
    dataframe = dataframe.drop([f], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say your prefix is `local_address_0.0.0.0`. The following code renames the columns that start with the prefix you specify to the index that column has according to the order in which they appear in the dataframe:

```
prefix = 'local_address_0.0.0.0'
cols = list(dataframe)
for idx, val in enumerate(cols):
    if val.startswith(prefix):
        dataframe.rename(index=str, columns={val: idx}, inplace=True)
```

This will show a warning in the console:

```
python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py:3027: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas- 
docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
return super(DataFrame, self).rename(**kwargs)
```

But it is just a warning, the column names of the dataframe are updated. If you want to learn more about the warning, see [How to deal with SettingWithCopyWarning in Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas)

If someone knows how to do the same thing without a warning, please comment.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC

```
dummydf=pd.get_dummies(df.A)
dummydf.columns=['A']*dummydf.shape[1]
dummydf
Out[1171]: 
   A  A
0  1  0
1  0  1
2  1  0
df
Out[1172]: 
   A  B  C
0  a  b  1
1  b  a  2
2  a  c  3
```